# what is the difference between payable and view in a smart contract in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, payable, view

I don't quite understand the concept of **payable** in a function in the smart contract and the difference between payable ,view and pure.

Answer (score 1):

**Payable** means that the function can receive Ether via that function call.  Comments in [this](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#function-modifiers) contract explain this modifier.

**View** means that the function only reads from member variables contained within the contract.  Explained [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#view-functions).

**Pure** states that no member variables within the contract are read from — all required data is in scope *within* the function itself.  Explained [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#pure-functions).

Answer (score 1):

`Payable` function means that you will send some ETH with the function. If you don't send any ETH with it, `transaction` will fail.

`View` is used to return data from function. Such function will read contract `state/storage`.

`Pure` is the same as `View`, except you can't read `state/storage` in it, but only do calculations with passed `parameters` or variables created inside function.

`View` and `Pure` are gas free when called from outside the contract or from other `View/Pure` function. If you call such function from inside normal function (which changes contract state), you will be charged however.